# PHP Multidimensional Array Key Values

Tags: php

I am trying to build a query builder for my Project, where I can pass any array, do the SELECT statement, return results and format them back in JavaScript.

I have been trying for a few days to get this to work, but I am somewhat a novice in PHP and quite frankly the manuals dont seem to be helping.

First I build the following Array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < FormSelect.length; i++){
    if(FormSelect[i].selectedIndex != 0){
        if(WhereClause.length == 0){
            var WhereObject = {
                ColumnName: FormSelect[i].id,
                ColumnValue: FormSelect[i].value
            }
        }
        else{
            var WhereObject = {
                Operator: " AND ",
                ColumnName: FormSelect[i].id,
                ColumnValue: FormSelect[i].value
            }
        }
    }
    WhereClause.push(WhereObject);
}
```

I then send the request to the server as follows, which all works fine:

```
var FormSearchData = 
    "ColumnNames=" + ColumnNames
    + "&"
    + "ViewName=" + ViewName
    + "&"
    + "WhereClause=" + WhereClause
    + "&"
    + "FormSearchExecuted=1"

var FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.onload = function(){
    console.log(FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.responseText);
}
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.open("POST", RootData + "global/search/search.php", false);
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.send(FormSearchData);
```

Server Side in PHP is where problems begin.

```
if(isset($_POST["FormSearchExecuted"]) && !empty($_POST["FormSearchExecuted"])){

if(empty($_POST["ColumnNames"])){
    $column_names = "*";
}
else{
    $column_names = $_POST["ColumnNames"];
}
if(!empty($_POST["WhereClause"])){

    if(count($_POST['WhereClause']) == 1){
        $form_search_sql = "DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR SET @ColumnNames = ? DECLARE @ViewName VARCHAR(255) SET @ViewName = ? DECLARE @WhereColumn VARCHAR SET @WhereColumn = ? DECLARE @WhereValue VARCHAR SET @WhereValue = ? EXEC('SELECT ' + @ColumnNames + ' FROM ' + @ViewName + ' WHERE ' + @WhereColumn + ' = ' + @WhereValue)";
    }

    foreach($_POST['WhereClause'] as $where){
        echo $where['ColumnName'];
    }

    $form_search_parameters = array($column_names, array(&$_POST["ViewName"]), array(&$_POST["WhereClause"]));
}
```

I am struggling to return the ColumnName, ColumnValue and Operator Keys in PHP, as i want to pass them as variables into the parameterised query. Any help would be greatly appreciated, to get me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole way is leading you to use GET method, but you use POST.

Try to change POST to GET, see if it helps, and get back here.

In your js try this:

```
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", RootData + "global/search/search.php&" + FormSearchData , false);
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
FormSearchXMLHTTPRequest.send();
```

And in php surely change all `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Also try to put a semicolon after you set `var FormSearchData = ... ;`

---

To use POST you d better send your FormSearchData as an object:

```
var FormSearchData = {
  "ColumnNames": ColumnNames,
  "ViewName": ViewName,
  "WhereClause": WhereClause,
  "FormSearchExecuted": 1
};
```

---

Also, use `var_dump($_POST)` to see what is missing

Comment: And? What holds him to set it GET? What you are donwvoting for?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but POST is used when you are using form input to query. Of which I am

Comment: surely, for private and security reasons. But, for now, it would be more important to make it work, so to find some light in debugging. If it works, then he could easily fix his code to use POST.

Comment: so, how is it going?

Comment: im not sure if there is some confusion in my question, I dont have any issues in actually passing the data and executing it via PHP, the issue I have is knowing how to call objects within an array that have been POSTED

Comment: ok, i was just not sure that it is being passed successfully, cause if so and `$_POST` is not empty and relevant keys `isset()`- then you should not have any problems with calling existing key and its value

Comment: yes everything is being passed properly, I need to iterate over the multidimensional array and return specific key values to use in building the query

Comment: and you say that `$_POST['WhereClause']` is set and not empty and, yet, this code `foreach($_POST['WhereClause'] as $where){
        echo $where['ColumnName'];
    }` is not echoing anything?

Comment: let me get back as the array is as follows: ["WhereClause"]=>
  string(54) ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: sorry, i m confused again - you ve posted the log of js object now, - so where you have you problems - in php or in js? As I understand you for now - you have no problems with getting $_POST and its values, but cannot return data to the frontend and get it with js properly. Am I right now?

Comment: the problem is PHP, as above I am trying to iterate through the array but get the following error:

Comment: string(15) "[object Object]"
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148915/discussion-between-cocostru-and-thetechnicalpaladin).